# AWS Lambda Function Keep It Alive

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a nodejs function on AWS Lambda that runs multiple setTimeouts within Async Parallel. Some are instant and some could be in 30min+ from now. The problem I am running into is that It will never get to the 30min timeout because it is going idle and then dies. Is there anyway to keep the lambda function alive while it is waiting to fire off the other timeout functions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The lifetime of a Lambda is maximum of 300 seconds.

See: [AWS Lambda Limits](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/limits.html)

There is **no way to increase** it beyond 300 seconds. When Lambda was introduced, the maximum execution time was 60 seconds. It was later increased to 300 seconds.

You need to revisit your design and check if Lambda is the correct solution. Running an on-demand EC2 instance that matches Lambda specifications could be a solution. Or state your problem, and we can propose a solution.

Comment: I changed routes completely. I made an express nodejs app that just listens for post requests and runs the setTimeouts in the background. No time limits that way.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to the fact that you can’t do that, see hellov’s answer, I would say that this is an incorrect design choice anyway.  If you needed a long lived service, using an ec2 instance directly would be a better choice.

If you just need to do something once 30 minutes later, then I would see about generating a AWS Lambda event at that time outside of the lambda code itself.  In other words, Lambda is meant for pure calculations, waiting for anything inside it seems the Wrong Approach.

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, there is a hard-limit of 300 seconds for the maximum execution time for a Lambda function. Based on the quick overview of your problem, I don't think Lambda is the correct solution.

If you need to handle these long-running asynchronous tasks then you will need to add some type of "connector" between these different tasks. One possible solution is to use [SQS Queues](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-message-lifecycle.html).

Component A --> SQS 1 --> Component B

Answer (score 1):

Your Lambda function does some parallel tasks. The best way to do this in Lambda is to split each task into a separate Lambda and then coordinate those tasks in a way that best makes sense to your application.

This can be done in several different ways (the best approach depends on your application):

1. [Step Functions](https://aws.amazon.com/step-functions/)
2. AWS Lambda + SNS
3. AWS Lambda + SNS/SQS
4. AWS Lambda + Kinesis
5. AWS Lambda + DynamoDB Streams

Comment: If you describe what those parallel tasks are, we can better recommend which approach is better for your use case.